# Data structure using master id

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, relational-database

I have a database with tables A and B in a one-to-many relationship. So one entity in A can be assigned to multiple and differing entities in B. A and B each have their own specific fields, but there are also fields and workflows related to either A or B, which are basically the same data but related only to either A or B.

As an example, an entity in A can have multiple comments for differing reasons and so can entities in B. Since there can be multiple comments for a single record I have to have a related comment table outside of tables A and B. I didn't want to have two comment tables, one for A and a separate table for B, so I set up a MasterID table that is related to both A and B and has referential integrity enforced. This means that when I want to add a record in A or B, I have to make sure that a MasterID already exists in the MasterID table. There are other tables that have the same type of functionality, comments is just one example, but if I didn't use a MasterID I'd have to create multiple tables each for A and B.

So my question is, is this the correct way to do this? Is there another way?  The front-end will be in Access so I'm running into a little bit of trouble making sure a MasterID is created right before creating a new record in A or B.

```
MasterID(MasterID)

TableA(TableAID, FK_MasterID)

TableB(TableBID, FK_MasterID, FK_TableAID)

Comments(CommentID, MasterID, Comment)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a pure data design standpoint, you are on the right track, but not quite.  You can use an **entity-subtyping** approach in which `A` and `B` are subtypes of another entity (`MasterID`).  It is this supertype entity which attracts comments.  However, for this to be true subtyping, the PK of `A` and the PK of `B` would be the FK to `MasterID`.

The way you've designed your tables, they have two candidate keys.  If you eliminate the redundant candidate keys, then you have a standard entity-subtyping pattern, which is a legitimate and commonly used design approach.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Comments is not the only table with similar data between A and B, but is an example of one set of multivalued dependency data required that is of the same type between A and B, but also unique to A or B. I changed the structure a little bit so now I have: TableA(PK_MasterID); TableB(PK_MasterID); MasterID(PK_MasterID); Comments(PK_CommentID, Comments, FK_MasterID). It's still not as easy as normal to add a record to A or B because a MasterID must exist first, but does this seem to be correct or would you have any further suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: @user3043701 - Your updated structure is correct.  This won't be easy to implement, especially in Access, since you don't have the full power of stored procedures or other methods which let you wrap multiple table writes into a single transaction (logical unit of work).  However, this structure is the most theoretically correct and will transfer well to more full-scale DBMS in the future should that be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed the difficulties this is creating. It's almost unusable. There is no data that is similar enough between A and B to be part of the MasterID table(Like FirstName/LastName) so all I have is a masterID field which is auto numbered. Access won't let me add any records to a table with only an auto numbered primary key. I was hoping MasterID would auto number then the sub tables would inherit that as their primary key, but no luck. So while correct, the solution doesn't seem to be functional. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: @user3043701 If the most important thing is to make Access happy then the best compromise would be to have two different `COMMENT` tables, one for each kind of thing (`A` and `B`).  This way you can define the FK's as _relationships_ in Access and then Access will give you all kinds of no-code goodness.  Then if you want to have a single view of all comments, you could define a view (union query) which brings them together in a view that looks a little bit like your first idea.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding for the problem, I think this is too complex for a little value. If I understand you correctly, you have a situation like the picture and you want to make the key for Comment unique.

Creating a fourth table could work but it adds unnecessary complexity.

What you could do instead is to make the key for the Comments table a compound key of the two columns one is a sequence number and the other is a character field indicating the parent table. So you get keys like (A,1), (A,2), (B,3), (A,4), (B,5) ...etc.

This way you don't need the master table, and you don't need FKs in Table A or B.

[image]